# how to send application request to my friend using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please anybody help me how i can send application request to somebody on facebook using graph API for example if i have logged in and i want to send application request to one of my friend using graph API how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app_id = "your application id";
$canvas_page = "your canvas page link";
$message = "Inviting you to my application";
$requests_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
. "&message=" . $message;
if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
  echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
} else {
  echo "Request Ids: ";
  print_r($_REQUEST["request_ids"]);
}
```